# Angular 2 & Slim PHP Framework: How to properly escape a string for use in a GET request

Tags: angular, api, escaping, slim, slim-4

## Environment

I have a frontend built using Angular2 which communicates with an API built using Slim PHP Framework v4.

Within the Angular frontend, a user can enter text into a form and submit it, then receive a response from the API.

The Angular project makes a request to the URL `/api/{text}`.

As far as I am aware, there is no way to access arguments supplied via, for example, `/api?text={text}` in Slim v4 and so I am unable to utilise Angular's `HttpParams` feature. For this reason, the URL is passed to Angular's `HttpClient` directly. i.e.

```
let text = 'Some random text / with special characters \.';
let myObservable: Observable<MyResponseObject[]>;
myObservable = this.http.get<MyResponseObject[]>(
  'http://my.domain.name/api/' + text
).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

## Problem

I have read that certain characters are encoded, then decoded again by Angular prior to submitting a request (i.e. `\`,`/`,`.`). For this reason, the value of the `text` variable in the above example is invalid.

One solution is to manually create a regex statement and use it to encode the string prior to submitting a request, then decode the string within the API.

I would like to avoid this and so I am wondering if one of two things is possible:

1. Is there any Javascript, Typescript or Angular feature for encoding strings, as described, for use within a URI?
2. Is there any way that I can access the value of arguments supplied with the format `?text={text}` from a GET request within Slim version 4?

### *EDIT:*

I'm also using  custom provider within Angular to attach an auth token as a URL parameter in the format `?auth=[my_token_here]`. The token is attached to every request sent by Angular. The custom provider uses the following code to attach the parameter:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  return this.authService.user.pipe(take(1), exhaustMap(user => {
    if(!user) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      params: new HttpParams().set('auth', user.token)
    });
    return next.handle(modifiedReq);
  }));
}
```

I've worked out how to read the value of 'auth' from the Slim API. However, when I modify the get request to add the `text` variable as a parameter, the parameter is never submitted and the Slim API still only sees the `auth` parameter. The modified code is as follows:

```
myObservable = this.http.get<MyResponseObject[]>(
  'http://localhost:8080/ngrams/', {
  params: new HttpParams().set('text', text)
}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

So here there are no errors, but the 'text' parameter is never attached to the URL (I can see only the auth parameter when checking the browser's network tab when I submit the request).

I'm an Angular noob so this logic may be flawed, but the above code for authentication was copied from a tutorial. My thinking is that maybe assigning `new HttpParams()` in the auth provider is overriding the parameters I set for the get request.

When I create the same request manually or using Postman, so the URL in my local environment is `http://localhost:8080/api/?text=some text goes here`, then I can successfully retrieve the parameter using the `$req->getQueryParams()` method.

Comment: I have no problem sending them, but Slim doesn't understand the format. The URL must be /api/{text} and not /api?={text}. The request is made successfully if I use HttpParams, but my API has no way of interpreting the parameter because it is formatted as ?text={text}

Comment: You can easily retrieve parameters that are sent in URL, i.e something like `?param=value`. Could you please provide a real example URL including real encoded value for `text` parameter? Something like `/api?text=some-value`.

Comment: I'm running on localhost, so at the moment I'm using the test sentence 'this is a good sentence'. So, in this case, it's `let text = 'this is a good sentence';` and then I pass the URL the same as in the example, but with localhost.. so `'http://localhost:8080/api/' + text`.

Comment: I've made some progress. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Nima's answer, the values were being read correctly by the Slim API when using `getQueryParams()`. The issue was that the parameters were not being sent in the first place.

The problem was that my authentication service was assigning a new `HttpParams` object to http requests, where it should have been adding an auth token to the existing set of parameters.

This issue was solved by updating the `intercept()` method mentioned in the question, so that the `auth` token is attached to the request's existing `params` property:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  return this.authService.user.pipe(take(1), exhaustMap(user => {
    if(!user) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      params: req.params.set('auth', user.token)
    });
    return next.handle(modifiedReq);
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Slim 4 documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/request.html#the-request-uri):

> You can get the query parameters as an associative array on the Request object using `getQueryParams()`.

Here is an example:

```php
$app->get('/api', function($request, $response, $args){
    $response->getBody()->write('<pre>' . print_r($request->getQueryParams(), 1) . '</pre>');
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

If you visit `/api?text=special chars %3A%20 \ %2F %3F %25 %26 ^ %23` the result is:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [text] => special chars :  \ / ? % & ^ #
> )
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question. It does work. When I set the URL manually in the browser, or when I use Postman, `getQueryParams()` does return the `text` parameter, but when I set it via HttpParams in Angular, it doesn't get sent.